# In Antlr4 enter listener, accessor function unexpectedly returns null

Tags: antlr4

I have the following Antlr4 grammar:

```
grammar CategoryExpr;
@header {
package org.example.antlr;
}
moneyTerm
    : dollars moneyTermSuffixes*
    ;

moneyTermSuffixes
   : '*' DIGITS # MoneyMult
   | '/' DIGITS # MoneyDiv
   ;

dollars : DIGITS ('.' DIGITS)? ;

DIGITS : [0-9]+ ;

ERRORCHAR : . ;
```

and the following Kotlin code:

```
private class MyListener : CategoryExprBaseListener() {
    override fun enterMoneyTerm(ctx: MoneyTermContext) {
        System.out.println(ctx.dollars().text.toDouble()) // ctx.dollars() unexpectedly returns null here!
    }
    override fun exitMoneyMult(ctx: CategoryExprParser.MoneyMultContext) {}
    override fun exitMoneyDiv(ctx: CategoryExprParser.MoneyDivContext) {}
    override fun exitMoneyTerm(ctx: MoneyTermContext) {
        System.out.println(ctx.dollars().text.toDouble()) // ctx.dollars() returns non-null here.
    }
}

fun testMoneyTerm() {
    val input = CharStreams.fromString("1.5")
    val lexer = CategoryExprLexer(input)
    val tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    val listener = MyListener()
    CategoryExprParser(tokens).apply {
        errorHandler = BailErrorStrategy()
        buildParseTree = false
        addParseListener(listener)
        moneyTerm()
    }
}
```

My plan was to use the enterMoneyTerm listener callback function to initialize a member variable (property) of MyListener to the value matching the 'dollars' parsing rule, and then have listeners for exitMoneyMult and exitMoneyDiv modify that variable's value by multiplying or dividing by the DIGITS values associated with each of these rules.

However, this approach does not seem to be working, because within the enterMoneyTerm function, if I try to evaluate 'ctx.dollars()' it unexpectedly returns null. (I can't seem to retrieve the value associated with 'dollars' within the call to enterMoneyTerm.)

Note that if I call ctx.dollars().text in exitMoneyTerm, I get the correct value ("1.5") returned, but by then, of course, it's too late, since I need to do my multiplications and divisions from left to right, and by that point, I have already recursed out of moneyTermSuffixes.

I don't understand why this "returning null from ctx.dollars()" behavior would be happening, or what to do about it. (In debugging, I have observed that MoneyTermContext object has its 'children' object set to null, which explains why dollars() returns null, but is itself unexplained.)

I suppose I could make a list of the multiplications and divisions implied by moneyTermSuffixes and then apply them after the fact in exitMoneyTerm, but this seems rather inelegant, and I would rather avoid it if possible.

Can anyone explain to me why ctx.dollars() is returning null in enterMoneyTerm, or what I can do about it so that I can gather the value of the 'dollars' text before parsing moneyTermSuffixes?

*Edit:* To clarify, note that converting to using a tree-walker-based approach instead of a listener-based approach is not really an option for me in the context of my larger application. I am hoping that there is a way to minimally modify my grammar to ensure that the parser has invoked a listener callback to provide me with the full textual value that the 'dollars' rule matched before it starts issuing callbacks for the moneyTermSuffixes rule.

Comment: How are you applying your listener? Do you use `ParseTreeWalker` or `Parser.addParseListener`?

Comment: I am using addParseListener. You can see the call to it in the Kotlin code sample.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't read the code very carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `Parser.addParseListener`, the listener will be invoked while the parser is parsing. The `enter` method will be invoked before the subexpressions are parsed and the `exit` methods after the subexpressions have been parsed.

So that explains why the children are `null` in the context object: They haven't been parsed yet, so no parse tree has been constructed.

To avoid this issue, you can use `ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk` instead of `addParseListener` to apply the listener after the whole parse tree has been constructed.

Comment: Hmm. This makes me wonder why the context is passed into the 'enter' function at all. I am aware that I can use tree walking instead of listeners to avoid this issue. However, in my larger application's grammar , of which this grammar is only a small subset, it is considerably preferable to use listeners, so unfortunately this solution doesn't really work for me. Is there a way that I can restructure my grammar to force the 'dollars' rule to be fully executed before the 'moneyTermSuffixes' rule?

Comment: @SomeGuy `ParseTreeWalker` isn't an alternative to listeners (`walk` still takes a listener as an argument). It's an alternative (or rather the preferred) way to apply listeners. Can you explain why using `addParseListener` is preferable in your case? If you really have to use `addParseListener, you'll probably just have to live with not being able to use the children in `enter` methods - I don't think there's a way around that when using `addParseListener`.

Comment: Also be aware that [when using addParseListener the enter methods may not always be called when you expect](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/802).

Comment: I am mostly using addParseListener for speed and to avoid creating another entire temporary extra AST data structure when what I am trying to do is create my own data structure in my enter and exit callbacks already.

In any case, with your explanation of the behavior of enter being invoked before subexpressions, but exit afterwards, I was able to come up with a solution: Set my variable in exitDollars (where the value of dollars is known) instead of in enterMoneyTerm (where it isn't yet). This seems to work. Marking this as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help!